# how to find row to row correspondence between two matrices in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have two matrices

```
A=[1 3;4 5;7 8;17 11]
```

and

```
B=[4 5;9 10;7 8;4 5;1 3;7 8;11 12].
```

I want to get a correspondence between different rows of the two matrices exactly like

```
[I,J] = find(pdist2(A,B)==0);
display([I,J]).
```

In my case the length of A and B is huge, so performing pdist2 is not memory efficient.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what I have done is:

```
[lib,loa] = ismember(B,A,'rows');

loa(loa==0)=[];

I = loa;

J = find(lib);

display([I,J]);
```

I hope there is no bug. It was quite easy at the end. Thank you very much for helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ismember`

```
[tf, index]=ismember(B,A,'rows');
```

where index contans indcies of equal rows of A to B and others will get zero
and if you want get those rows in B use

```
index(index==0) = []
rows=A(index,:)
```

See [http://www.mathworks.com/](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `bsxfun`. It will probably take less time than `pdist2`, but I'm not sure if it will be more memory-efficient:

```
[I, J] = find(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A.', permute(B.',[1 3 2])))));
```

Comment: +1, `find`, `squeeze`, `all`, `bsxfun` and `permute` in a single line... I guess you didn't get that one right on your first try =P

Comment: @RobertP. No, but almost ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: if you want (memory) efficiency, and you have a need that isn't quite readily solved by standard MATLAB functions, implement a custom solution:

```
inds = NaN(max(size(A,1),size(B,1)),2);
kk = 1;
for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    for jj = 1:size(B,1)
        if isequal(A(ii,:), B(jj,:))
            inds(kk,:) = [ii,jj];
            kk = kk+1;
        end
    end
end
inds = inds(1:kk-1,:)
```

The double-loop above is also the approach taken by `pdist2`. However, `pdist2` computes *all* distances, most of which you don't need for your purpose and just throw away. The same holds for the `bsxfun` approach taken by Luis.

This makes using `pdist2` or Luis' solution for your particular purpose equal to flying from London to Paris via the South pole, without even enjoying the view--not very fast, and indeed quite wasteful :) A loop tailored to your specific use case is going to be fastest and most memory efficient.

The double-loop above has O(N²) complexity. This also seems to be the method used by `ismember` (+1 to Alyafey!) It's faster and more memory efficient than the other solutions, however, I have a strong suspicion that O(N·log(N)) or better is possible for your particular case. Should you have to solve this problem thousands of times on millions of matrices in the next few weeks, I'd put in a bit of time to find the best algorithm, or prove that it's impossible :)